# "non-blob object size limit exceeded" from GitHub/git

Tags: git, github

I keep receiving the following error from git when I try to push my repository to GitHub. Any suggestions on how to progress?

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 111483, done.
Delta compression using up to 40 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (37859/37859), done.
Writing objects: 100% (111481/111481), 14.52 MiB | 413.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 111481 (delta 92154), reused 92835 (delta 73622)
remote: fatal: non-blob object size limit exceeded
error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To https://github.com/<my repository>
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<my repository>'
```

Comment: Git does not have object size limits, but GitHub does, depending on whether you pay them. The non-blob objects are trees, tags, and commits. It's unlikely that a tag or commit object is that big so this implies that you have some very large tree object, representing a directory with ten million files in it for instance. It's impossible to say more without insider knowledge about either GitHub or your repository, neither of which I have.

Comment: I would ask the question to GitHub via https://github.com/contact

Comment: Additionally GitHub doesn't have any set disk quotas. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive an email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down. In addition GitHub places a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size. More information at: https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/

Comment: torek : You are right, that's the problem (confirmed by GitHub) -- I had a too large directory. I have now given a generic answer, mainly for if someone else finds this page when googling the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused by a file in git's internal data store being too large, and github rejecting files which are too large. There are three common ways to make files which are too large:

- Commit a single file which is extremely large
- A single commit where you change too many files
- A directory which contains too many files

(This is based on @torek's comment leading me in the right direction).

Comment: What is GAP?  Is that a typo for Git or are you using some program called GAP on top of Git that is trying to use it like a database?

Comment: GAP happens to be what I'm storing in my git repository, and I mistyped. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  :)

Comment: To clarify a couple of things:  a single large file will give a similar, but different, error message telling you _which_ file is too large.  (Large files trigger the _blob_ object size limit.)  A large directory will trigger this, as will a large commit, but a commit object's size is independent of the files changed, you would have to craft a commit with a very large message or other metadata.  (Git doesn't store the list of files changed between commits.)  Finally, we (GitHub) have changed this message to provide more information about which non-blob object is too large.